# Show all objects in SearchQuerySet when no_query_found

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm trying to return all objects in the `SearchQuerySet` whenever a user first navigates to the search page (and so has not yet entered a query). According to the docstring for `no_query_found` method of the `SearchForm`:

```
def no_query_found(self):
    """
    Determines the behavior when no query was found.
    By default, no results are returned (``EmptySearchQuerySet``).
    Should you want to show all results, override this method in your
    own ``SearchForm`` subclass and do ``return self.searchqueryset.all()``.
    """
    return EmptySearchQuerySet()
```

So, following these instructions, I have tried:

```
class MySearchForm(SearchForm):

    def no_query_found(self):

        return self.searchqueryset.all()
```

However, this returns an empty list as a result. It seems that I'm having a similar issue to [this one](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1021). I'm wondering if this has been fixed and if not what is the best way to return all objects in the relevant `SearchQuerySet` so that I can show users all results before they search.

If it's useful, my view is basically:

```
MySearchView(haystack.generic_views.SearchView):
    form_class = MySearchForm
```

One more note, everything works fine when I enter a search string, so this is an isolated issue (i.e. I have run `rebuild_index` etc.).